# Way to show US territories in R maps package

Tags: r, maps

I was wondering whether it was possible in the maps package to map us territories in combination with a map of the continental united states.

```
map("state")
points(data$LONGITUDE, data$LATITUDE, pch = 20, col = alpha(ifelse(data$known == 1, "red", "blue"), 0.3), cex = 0.5)
```

I'm using the above code to create my map, but my dataframe "data" contains lat and long for alaska, hawaii, and puerto rico.  How could I also include those in my map?

Let me know if I can add additional clarity!

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `raster` package to get USA borders:

```
library(raster)
USA <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Typed the above two lines, ran them with cmd+enter which worked. After that I tried to run 'plot(USA)' as suggested in http://data-analytics.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/geo2.html but my laptop is taking forever to load the map. Am I to do something else before I call the plot function?

I tried expanding the plot window is RStudio and also clicking the broomstick icon. Nothing seems to help. Please guide. TIA.